# How to send the HttpResponse including both JSON and html

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp, struts

In my application, dynamic data are retrieved in 2 ways to the page

1. After the page is loaded, send ajax request and retrieve data as JSON
2. At the time of page generated, the JSON data are written to page in server side where javascripts locate  (for example in JSP. `var data='<%=jsonData%>';`)

   As I found in google, there are suggestions to send the html in JSON as JSON value and get back in browser ([like this](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-practice-to-return-both-HTML-and-JSON-in-an-Ajax-response)).

I want to get both the html page and the json data together without above steps. Any suggetions please ?

Note: I use Spring, Struts frameworks. Even with support of such frameworks, any possible way ?

Comment: Curious to know the reason for not getting them with two responses?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem at all returning HTML as a JSON value (but it's not recomended. That's why [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is so good). You just have to be careful with some characters that may break your JSON return. Example:

Escape quotes:

```
var myobject = {
  name: 'contentHTML',
  value: '<div><a href="#" onclick="goTo(\'test.html\')"></a></div>'               
};
```

It's also a good idea replace break lines:

```
var myobject = {
  name: 'contentHTML',
  value: '<div><a href="#" onclick="goTo(\'test.html\')">
         </a></div>'   // It will not work.            
};
```

in your HTML you can do something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('#myContent').append(myobject.value);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this way has already been noted in my question itself. As you mentioned, it is not generally recommended and that is why I asked another way to do it. Once again, appreciate and thanks nanndoj for your answer.

Comment: I recommend you to use AngularJS. It is awesome organizing HTML and JSON response